# Buttons in iPad not clickable

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating buttons using data from array. It should look like the following:

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
        super.viewDidLoad()    

     var xMargin:CGFloat = 20.0
     var yTopMargin:CGFloat = 40.0


     var i = 1


     let DataTanks = ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", "Button 4", "Button 5", "Button 6"]

     for index in 0...5
     {
     let button = UIButton()
     button.tag=index
     var buttonFrame = self.view.frame
     buttonFrame.origin.x += xMargin
     buttonFrame.origin.y += yTopMargin
     buttonFrame.size.width = 200
     buttonFrame.size.height = 200

     button.frame = buttonFrame
     button.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
     button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 64/255, green: 64/255, blue: 64/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
     button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
     button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
     button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)
     button.layer.zPosition = 10

     button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
     button.enabled=false

     if(index==2)
     {
        button.enabled=true
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 153/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
     }
     if(index==3)
     {
        button.enabled=true
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 102/255, alpha: 1.0)
     }

    button.setTitle(DataTanks[index], forState: UIControlState.Normal)   
    button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 3;     
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTestViewController.didTouchButton), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

     self.view.addSubview(button)


     xMargin+=250.0

     i+=1

        if(i > 3 )
        {
            yTopMargin+=300.0
            xMargin=20.0

            i=1
        }
     }

  }


func didTouchButton(sender:UIButton!) {

        print("Button - \(btnsendtag.tag)")
    }
```

Using the above code, a few buttons are clickable but others are not. Not sure what's causing the button not to work. Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal because you disactivated all other buttons except with index 2 and 3.

```
button.enabled=false
```

^ this is 'what's causing the button not to work'